# Running Java servlet program it is not insert values into data base sqlserver 2008

Tags: java, xml, jsp, servlets

I am trying to insert values into data base table it is not inserting it shows `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 0 is out of range.` exception and here i am using sql server 2008 database and how can i insert values into database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PreparedStatement parameter indexes start at 1 - so you probably just want

```
 setString(1, Userid[0]);
```

Comment: Is there any way to call parameters here i am taking ` ps.setString(9,FName); ` i have 9 columns it's ok but when i have 15 columns how can i take those values is there anyway could you please tell me thank you

Answer (score 0):

While setting the parameters in the prepared statement the indexes start with 1 and not 0, hence the exception is thrown. So, in your code it should start with

ps.setString(1, Userid value );

And to siplify your code, you can store the request parameter values into an arraylist and iterate through the list and set the value in prepared statement using only one set statement.